# Xamarin forms material buttons corner radius issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement material design in our cross platform app. when I use corner radius on button, on android it works fine but on iOS I get below result but when I remove corner radius it renders properly:

the code is as simple as   with visual material in the contentpage

[image: Button iOS Issue]

Comment: can you post your code? are you using a custom renderer? you can use `Visual="Material"` to get a pre-baked material design aesthetic. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual

Comment: if you add corner radius to their buttons in the sample. you will get the above result as well

Comment: Yes, but the question is what is your buttons' height and what corner radius have you set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This weird appearance occurs when your button doesn't have enough height to display corner radius.
setting the height 2 multipliers to the radius resolves the issues and renders the button properly